# Internet Explorer font color bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

At the moment I'm having issues with IE for font colors. In my CSS I've specified color but for some reason IE is ignoring this.

http://www.james-hayward.com/property_type/for-sale/

color is set here:

```
.entry-info a {
    color: #663399;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This appears to be for all versions of IE (so the usual IE6/7/8 fixes seem useless)

Comment: you should validate your markup first....you have an anchor element closing on line 78 that is preventing ie's f12 tools to see what exactly is going on. that may fix your problem, but even if it doesn't, it'll let us see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have your rule the wrong way round, it should be `a .entry-info`.. but the way you've written it is bad in my opinion.

This might work

```
.entry-info h1 {
    color: #663399;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: you can nest elements in anchors in html5

Comment: `div` inside an `a` is just fine in html5. But yeah, your `a` is outside of your `div.entry-info`, so your rule is in the wrong order

Comment: sorry yeh you are correct, i didnt notice it was html5 :-) edited

Answer (score 1):

use this `.entry-info h1 {
    color: #663399;}`

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your element nesting is a little out as although this will work in HTML5, a simple change can make it cross browser compatible and avoid any issues on that front (Support for HTML5 is extremely limited in IE7,8 and none existant in IE 6) I would recommend moving your  inside your H1 and then referencing it as so:

```
.entry-info h1 a {
    color: #663399;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As well as this, the pasted you rule you provide is in the wrong order as your a is currently outside your `.entry-info` style.